# How to add just one string in Crowdin?

Tags: translation

How do I add just 1 (one) string in Crowdin? The only way to create a new key that I see now is to upload a Localizable.strings file. But it would be more convenient to add a string with some sort of "+" button or whatever. Can't find it.